# Check all weekends dynamically from api data using moment.js in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to check weekends in my react code. I am using moment.js and API data. I want to return all the non-working day which is Saturday and Sunday in the array and print it in the console.

How can I achieve all the non-working day dynamically using **moment.js**

[Stackblitz - Originial code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-recharts-y917mu)

[image: API DATA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with ES6 filter array method:

```
const arrayOfWeekendItems = chartData.filter(item => {
  // Get day of provided data 
  const day = moment(item.date).day()
  // Return true if it's saturday or sunday, either false
  return day === 6 || day === 0
})
const sequence = arrayOfWeekendItems.map(item => item.date)
```

Remember that correct day number may wary, depending on moment.js ["Locale aware" settings](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not in sequence. How can I arrange in the right order? is there any way ?

Comment: After filtering you can use ".sort()" method on returned array. With moment.js you easily compare two "moment(yourDate)" objects using for example '-' or '<' '>'.

Comment: you mean something like this .sort((a, b) => a.itemM > b.itemM). what value should i compare?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want to order your filtered array by date. In your case it should look like this: .sort((a, b) => moment(a.date) > moment(b.date) ).

Comment: Oh, so instead of sorting you can use '.map' method and return only date value from it: .map(item => item.date). See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the filter function on chartData:

```
const filterDates = (dateStr) => {
    let day = moment(dateStr).day();
    return day == 0 || day == 6;
}

const Timedata = this.state.chartData.filter( i => filterDates(i.date) );
```

That will return a list of objects. You would also have to update your render function so that it uses `Timedata`.

```
Timedata.map( (obj) => {
    ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not in sequence date. How can I arrange in the right order?